# Get numbers greater than n

Tags: javascript

I need to `console.log` every number that is greater than 10 from this row

`[ 10, 10, 11, 12, 156, 9, 3, 5, 1, 61, 89, 5, 6]`

I know it should be something like this

```
var row = [ 10, 10, 11, 12, 156, 9, 3, 5, 1, 61, 89, 5, 6];
for (var i = 0; i<row; i++)
{
    console.log(niz[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you don’t actually need to log them but to use them as an array, use `filter` instead: `row.filter(function(a){return a > 10;});`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could either use a `for` loop or mapping. For loop would be like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<row.length; i++)
{
  if (row[i] > 10)  
   console.log(row[i]);
 }
```

To use mapping:

```
row.map(function(element){
 if (element > 10)  
   console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: No problem. If my answer was useful you could give me best answer by clicking the ✔ symbol.

Comment: Why `map()` and not `forEach()` or `filter()` or even `reduce()`?

Comment: It would be more complicated using `filter()` coz you’d first have to generate another filtered list and then you would loop again over its elements to log them. Also, `forEach()` is perfectly fine, I just wanted to introduce `map()` in case the user didn’t know about it. `forEach()` is technically a `for` loop too.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the question, you need to use a `for`-loop to iterate trough all the items in your array. This is almost done correctly, but instead of doing `i<row`, you need to check against the length of the `row` (`row.length`).

In your case, `i` will be the index in your list, and it will increment with one (`i++`) in each iteration in the `for`-loop until you reach the number of items in rows.

The thing that you are missing is a `if`-statement to check if the item in the array is greater than 10.

I've tried to explain each line with a comment.

```js
var row = [10, 10, 11, 12, 156, 9, 3, 5, 1, 61, 89, 5, 6];
var items = row.length; // number of items in your array

for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) { // iterate trough all the items
    var numberInRow = row[i]; // the number with index number i in rows
    var isGreaterThanTen = numberInRow > 10; // true if the number is greater than ten

    if (isGreaterThanTen) { // will execute if isGreaterThanTen is true
        console.log(numberInRow); // print number greater than 10 to console.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `forEach`-loop seems a nice way of solving your problem:

```
var row = [ 10, 10, 11, 12, 156, 9, 3, 5, 1, 61, 89, 5, 6];
row.forEach(function(x){if(x>10){console.log(x)}})
```

or even shorter

```
[10, 10, 11, 12, 156, 9, 3, 5, 1, 61, 89, 5, 6].forEach(function(x){if(x>10){console.log(x)}})
```

The output in both cases:

```
11
12
156
61
89
```